# How do I change how keys are serialized in Scalding?

Tags: scala, scalding

I am grouping by a custom type in my scalding job:

```
typedPipe
   .map(someMapper)
   .groupBy(_.nonPrimitiveField)
   .sum
   .write(sink)
```

In my output, the keys show up as the `toString` output, which is not useful. How can I make scalding use a custom serializer for these keys?

My current workaround is to call `toTypedPipe` and explicitly call my serialization function in the mappers, but this seems wasteful.

The sink is a `TypedTsv[(Key, Value)]`, where `Key` is the type of the field that I would like to serialize differently.

Comment: It depends of the type of the sink you are writing to. How do you create the sink?

Comment: @Dima updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `Tsv` is a text format, so, in the end of the day, everything becomes a string. 
The simplest way would be to just override `.toString` on your `Key` type, or wrap it into another object with `.toString` overridden. Or, just replace it with a `String` as a final step (I think, that's what you are already doing anyway). I am not sure what you mean when you say it is "wasteful". It does not add an extra step to the flow if that's your concern, and the conversion to string would have to happen in any case, so that cost is fixed.

```
typedPipe.
 .map(someMapper)
 .groupBy(x => beautifulString(x.nonPrimitiveField))
 .sum
 .write(sink)
```